# Update data in a table with jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to update a table according to ajax respond. My update should be insert as the first row inside `<tbody>` in my table. With my coding this is happening in my table when I insert data after page is loaded. My problem is when I insert data again without refreshing the page it insert to table as second row inside `<tbody>` and again insert another its going as third row and so on.

But when I am refreshing or reloading the page my table adjusts data in correct order.
Can anybody tell me how I fix this problem?

This is my code so far :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
    url: "process.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
    //dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        address: $('#address').val(),
        city: $('#city').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#manage_user table > tbody:first').append(data);
        //alert(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        //On error, we alert user
        alert(thrownError);
    },
    complete: function() {
        //alert('update success'); 
    }
});
```

**UPDATE :** This is HTML for my table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><input type='checkbox' class='selectAll' name='selectAll' value='' /> Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>

     // -------- this is the place I need to insert data 

     <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='' value='' class='' />&nbsp;&nbsp;sdfsdfs</td>
      <td>dsfs</td>
      <td>dsfdsf</td>
      <td><span class='edit_ico'></span></td>
      <td><span class='delete_ico'></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='' value='' class='' />&nbsp;&nbsp;aaaaaaa</td>
      <td>dfsdf</td>
      <td>dsfsf</td>
      <td><span class='edit_ico'></span></td>
      <td><span class='delete_ico'></span></td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#manage_user table > tbody:last').find('tr:first').before(data);
```

Try this. check my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/W4gYY/3/

If you declared thead then you can use `tbody:first` and working fine. You do not mention `thead` that is way html treated as default `tbody`

If your html look like below :

```
<div id="manage_user">
<table>
  <thead>  
  <tr>
    <th><input type='checkbox' class='selectAll' name='selectAll' value='' /> Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='' value='' class='' />&nbsp;&nbsp;sdfsdfs</td>
      <td>dsfs</td>
      <td>dsfdsf</td>
      <td><span class='edit_ico'></span></td>
      <td><span class='delete_ico'></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='' value='' class='' />&nbsp;&nbsp;aaaaaaa</td>
      <td>dfsdf</td>
      <td>dsfsf</td>
      <td><span class='edit_ico'></span></td>
      <td><span class='delete_ico'></span></td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

then you can use

```
$('#manage_user table > tbody:first').find('tr:first').before(data);
```

otherwise without `thead` in html you have to do following code

```
$('#manage_user table > tbody:last').find('tr:first').before(data);
```

Comment: Again it is updating above my table header.

Comment: Thanks som. This is the solution which I am looking for

Comment: som can you tell me how this selection being happen?

Comment: @TNK If you declared `thead` then you can use `tbody:first` and working fine. You do not mention `thead` that is way html treated as default `tbody`. Check my updated fiddle

Comment: @TNK Do you understand where is the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `html` instead of `append`

```
success: function(data) {
        $('#manage_user table > tbody:first').html(data);
        //alert(data);
}
```

Comment: I tried with `html` but then my table lost it hearder part and its style. Again after refreshing the page it is adjusting table in correct way.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your appending the data, you should use .html(data) then it will be replaced by your new data

Answer (score 0):

here the solution for you

OLD :

```
$('#manage_user table > tbody:first').append(data);
```

NEW :

```
$('#manage_user table > tbody').prepend(data);
```

You need to use prepend at the place of append

Comment: I tried this and data inserting to table but above in my table header.

Comment: I have a better idea for you , please set the `<tbody id="something">` like this $('#something').prepend(data); I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery method called [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) and it can do the thing you want...

```
$('#manage_user table > tbody:first').append(data);
```

can be changed to

`$('#manage_user tr:first').after('<tr><td>first</td></tr>');` 
which inserts the result as first row of the table... Check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qchfu/2/) here

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do this with my data

Comment: @TNK:updated my answer, Check the Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/qchfu/2/ for your code