# Update HTML from AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, html-table

My table is appended to instead of updated. What would be the appropriate way to update the html. I tried to use the [answer from a similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358771/update-data-in-a-table-with-jquery-and-ajax) but it didn't work.

Here's my webpage, which uses Bootstrap, and the relevant ajax:

```
<div class="bs-component">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
      <thead>
      <tr>
          <th style="font-size: 25px">Week <span id="week" style="font-size: 28px">1</span></th>
          <th>12 am - 8 am</th>
          <th>8 am - 12 pm</th>
          <th>12 pm - 4 pm</th>
          <th>4 pm - 8 pm</th>
          <th>8 pm - 12 am</th>

      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <script>
          function loadWeek (x) {
            $.post("weekly.php", {p: x}, function (res) {
               //$("tbody").append(res);
               $('#bs-component table > tbody:last').find('tr:first').before(res);
            });
          }
          $(function () {
            loadWeek (1);
          });
          </script>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Here's the html echoed by the php called by ajax

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    echo "<tr><td>$weekDays[$i]</td>";
    for ($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++) {
        echo "<td><p>".$usersNames[$i][$j]."</p></td>";
    }
    echo"</tr>";
}
```

Comment: _"Here's the html echoed by the php called by ajax"_ That's PHP, not HTML. And have you tried `replaceWith()` or `replaceAll()`?

Comment: @j08691 No I have not tried replaceWith() or replaceAll(). How would I use those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few small issues with your jQuery code. First, you want to move the `<script>` tag out of the table. It can be anywhere in the page, and typically goes at the bottom of the page (just before the closing body tag `</body>`). The reason you want to do this is that when the Ajax response returns, you want to replace the contents of the `<tbody>` which will overwrite your `<script>` tag.

Next, what you want to do with the response is replace the contents of the `<tbody>` (rather than append). I would rewrite your `loadWeek`  function as follows:

```
function loadWeek(x) {
  $.post('weekly.php', {p: x}, function(res) {
    $('#bs-component tbody').html(res);
  });
}
```

You can find the documentation for the `.html()` function at https://api.jquery.com/html/

Notice the selector is slightly different - because you only have 1 `<table>` inside your `<div>`, and that table only has 1 `<tbody>` inside that table, you don't have to specify the last `<tbody>` that is a direct descendant of a `<table>` (which is what the selector you have means).

Comment: Thanks @Bill-Hannah your explanation gave me all the necessary terminology to correctly fix the problem. It worked except in the `$('#bs-component tbody').html(res);` the `#` needs to be replacedwith `.` `$('.bs-component tbody').html(res);`. [link] (http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) shows that `.` selects div class and `#` selects div id.

Comment: Right you are. I didn't look too closely at the HTML. Glad you could get it working!