# data fades in the table after clicking the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How do I refresh the records in the data after clicking the button without reloading the whole page? I want to fade into table the data I'd add to the database. Thanks

Comment: This question is far too broad but you need to look into how to use ajax. Beyond that there simply isn't enough information here to tell you how to integrate it

Comment: You must see this answer :-
[Click on this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358771/update-data-in-a-table-with-jquery-and-ajax) Hope you got your answer

Comment: ok thanks for the information

Comment: i want to add effects in adding the records in the table. and add automatically to the table after clicking the button