# How to pull out mysql column values and put it in a <div> in the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Sorry if the question isn't clear what i am trying to do is something like this:

Say i have a table that consist of these rows:

```
//filename: stock.php
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT item_id item_name, item_price, item_desc FROM items");
while($show = mysqli_fetch_array('$result')){
    $item_id = ($show['item_id']);
    $item_name = ($show['item_name']);
    $item_price = ($show['item_price']);
    $item_desc = ($show['item_desc']);
?>

<tr>
<td class="item_id"><?php echo"$item_id"; ?></td>
<td class="item_name"><?php echo"$item_name"; ?></td>
<td class="item_price"><?php echo"$item_price"; ?></td>
<td class="item_desc"><?php echo"$item_desc"; ?></td>
<td><a href="#editItem" class="edit_item">Edit Item</a></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

What i want to do is that when i click on that edit item link, i will go to the div, and on that div, all the data from the mysql database that has the same item id will be pulled out, putted in textboxes in the pop-up div that is on the same web page(no need to refresh the page, and the data listed in the table is not all of them, so i can't just pull it from there since it doesn't have infos like arrival date, and the quantity of the item, and other stuffs), so how do i achieve that?

Comment: Do you use jQuery? It's much easier to code this with that library.

Comment: Yes, can you tell me the how to do that in jquery?

Comment: Bind a click handler to `.edit_item`. It can use `$(this).parent().siblings(".item_id").text()` to get the contents of the item ID cell, and similarly for the other cells. It can put these into the `.val()` of the textboxes in the dialog.

Comment: If you want to include information that isn't in the page, you could use AJAX to query for all the data for an item ID.

Comment: I could be wrong, but wouldn't if i use ajax then values i got would be sent to the stock.php page, but shouldn't the div has already been loaded when i first open the page? making the textboxes not displaying anything when the ajax has finished sending the values?

Comment: The question says you need to include data that isn't in the `stock.php` page. So you need to use AJAX to call another script that returns the additional data to put into the edit form.

Comment: OK, so i make another .php file that stores the values from the mysql query, and the passed it to the stock.php page?

Comment: No. You make another script that returns the data for a specific item ID in a JSON object. When the user clicks on the edit button, you call the script with `$.ajax`, and in the callback function you fill in the textboxes in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through documentations first, but still here is an example:

[Update data in a table with jquery and ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358771/update-data-in-a-table-with-jquery-and-ajax)

http://mrbool.com/how-to-add-edit-and-delete-rows-of-a-html-table-with-jquery/26721

http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/live-table-edit-with-jquery-and-ajax.html

Modal Popup:

```
<div id="edit_company_modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" id="edit_company_modal_close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Edit Company</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" id="edit_company_form">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Company Name*</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                    <input class="input focused" id="company_name" name="company_name" type="text">
                     <span id="company_name_error" class="error"></span>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Invoice Options*</label>
                    <div class="controls" id="invoice_select_container">
                    <!--Selection box will come here dynamically-->
                    </div>
            </div>  
                <div class="form-actions">
                                <input type="hidden" id="edit_company_id" name="edit_company_id">
                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="update_company_button" name="update_company_button" value="Update Company" >
                 </div>  
             </form>  
            </div>
</div>
```

Display Table:

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SI No</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Is Invoiced</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
       </tr>
       </thead>   
        <tbody>
       <?php
       if(mysql_num_rows($company_set)>0)
       { 
       $i=1;
 while($data_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($company_set))
{
$invoice_option_name=$common->getInvoiceOptionName($data_row['is_invoiced']);
?>
<tr id="<?php echo $data_row['id']; ?>">
<td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data_row['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $invoice_option_name; ?></a></td>
<td class="center">
<a class="btn btn-info edit_company_button" href="#">
<i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i>  
Edit                                           
</a>
<a class="btn btn-danger delete_company_button" href="#">
<i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>  
Delete                                          
</a>
</td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
<?php $i++; } } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery Call Filled Popup

```
$(document).on('click','.edit_company_button',function(){
var company_id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); // table row ID 
$('#edit_company_id').val(company_id);
var data ='company_id='+company_id+'&task=edit_company';
$.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: baseUrl+'classes/common.php',
                  data: data,
                  dataType:"json",
                  success: function(data) 
                          { 
                            $('#company_name').val(data.company_data.name);
                            var invoice_select_box=  "<select id='edit_invoice' name='edit_invoice' data-rel='chosen'>";                 
                                for(var i=0; i<data.invoice_options.length; i++)
                                {
                                    if(data.company_data.is_invoiced==data.invoice_options[i].id)
                                    invoice_select_box+= "<option value='"+data.invoice_options[i].id+"'>"+data.invoice_options[i].name+"</option>";
                                }
                                for(var i=0; i<data.invoice_options.length; i++)
                                {   
                                    if(data.company_data.is_invoiced!=data.invoice_options[i].id)
                                    invoice_select_box+= "<option value='"+data.invoice_options[i].id+"'>"+data.invoice_options[i].name+"</option>";
                                }
                                    invoice_select_box+= "</select>"+
                                                 "<span id='edit_invoice_error' class='error'></span>";
                            $('#invoice_select_container').html(invoice_select_box);                     
                            $('#edit_company_modal').modal('show');
                          }
});
});
```

Jquery Update

```
$(document).on('click','#update_company_button',function(){
var company_id = $('#edit_company_id').val();
var company_name = $('#company_name').val();
var invoice_option_id = $('#edit_invoice').val();
var data ='company_id='+company_id+'&company_name='+company_name+'&invoice_option_id='+invoice_option_id+'&task=update_company';
$.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: baseUrl+'classes/common.php',
                  data: data,
                  dataType:"json",
                  success: function(data) 
                          { 
                            if(data.success)
                            {       
                                $("#"+company_id+"  td:nth-child(2)").text(data.company_data.name);
                                 $("#"+company_id+"  td:nth-child(3)").text(data.invoice_name);
                                 $('#edit_company_modal_close').click();
                                 customResetDataTable();
                            }   
                        }
        });
});
```